# Non-commutative sum?

Tags: summation, numerical-methods, programming

I'm attemting to calculate
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10000} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ numerically, using a computer program. However, if I sum the terms in the natural order (starting from $n=1$ and going up one unit every time) I get a different result that if I compute the sum in the reversed order (starting from $n=10000$ and going down one unit at a time). I understand it must have something to do with the rounding the computer does in every single calculation but I can't seem to explain the phenomenon in a clear manner. Any help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The computer will be working in 64 bit binary too most likely. Each $\frac{1}{n^2}$ term will have a binary approximation before it is added to the running total (also in binary) which is then converted to decimal for display purposes. Lots of potential for rounding error.

Comment: do you reelly want to know the sum?

Comment: You have probably identified the reason. For a clear explanation you should probably delete here ask instead  at https://stackoverflow.com/ ,  and post the code you used

Comment: My objective is not to know the sum, but rather to understand why the order of summation matters.

Comment: I just used Microsoft Excel to add in both orders.  The result differed by roughly $5 \times 10^{-15}$.  So, my results don't align with your observation.

Comment: Computing the sum in the order $1/10000^2 + 1/9999^2 + 1/9998^2 +...$ will give you a more accurate result than computing in the order $1/1^2 + 1/2^2 + 1/3^2 +....$.  When computing the sum of a set of numbers in floating point arithmetic, it is best to start with the smaller numbers.

Comment: @MarkViola Excel does not necessarily add the numbers in the order you expect.

Comment: @awkward The way I configured the analysis, the sums were indeed sequential and in reverse order.

Comment: @MarkViola Although you list the numbers in one order, Excel may not sum them in that order.  In fact, if you have a multi-core system, Excel may even break the sum into different chunks to be run in parallel on multiple cores  So you really have no control over the order in which Excel sums the numbers.  If you want to control the order of computation, you need to write a program in a conventional programming language like C or Python.

Comment: @awkward You have no idea how I used Excel to sum the terms, now do you?  They were summed one at a time and listed one at a time.  That is, I created the partial sums from 1 to 10,000.  In one column the sum began top down, one row at a time with the last row providing the final partial sum.  In an adjacent column, the the sum began at the bottom.  Wha on earth are you talking about???

Comment: @MarkViola You are right, I misunderstood your initial comment.  I thought you were using the Excel worksheet function "sum".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a simpler example may help.  Let's say you have a computer that does decimal floating-point arithmetic with only $3$ digits, and you want to add
$999 + 1 + 1 + \ldots 1$ (with $100$ 1's).

If you do it in that order, the first addition gives you $999 + 1 = 1000 = 1.00 \times 10^3$, and each subsequent addition leaves it there ($1000 + 1 = 1001$, but rounded to $3$ digits that's still $1.00 \times 10^3$).

On the other hand, try it in the reverse order.  $1 + 1 = 2$, $2 + 1 = 3$, \ldots, $99 + 1 = 100$, and finally $100 + 999 = 1099 = 1.10 \times 10^3$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

The rounding (or better said "approximate representation") takes place both in the calculation of the fraction, as well as in the addition of the terms. The latter makes the result dependent on the order of additions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer